# multi line text box in sharepoint web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

How can I display a field that is a multi line text box in a sharepoint webpart?

when i click "modify shared webpart" on the webpart i would like the text field to me a multi line box

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll also have to write your rendering to be sensitive to what mode you're in:

```
if( (WebPartManager.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.DesignDisplayMode) || 
    (WebPartManager.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.EditDisplayMode) ) {
       //Show your textbox
} else {
       //Render as text
}
```